# Removing duplicates conditionally from excel table based on varied start and stop date selection

Tags: microsoft-excel

I am working on excel tables that have duplicates. I have to eliminate the duplicates from loc 3 and 4 (Column 4 and 5) based on earliest start date and latest end date. Duplicates from loc 1 and 2 (Column 2 and 3) SHOULD NOT be removed. For example Tylenol and Pepcid in the following: Only duplicates with a Yes in Loc 3 and 4 must be removed with earliest start date and latest end date (see desired output). I have a lot of complicated tables to do this. Does anyone have a suggestions?

[image]

Comment: Yes this is possible (most likely with VBA). However, SuperUser isn't a code-writing service, so please make some attempts first, and let us know what you tried, and what did/didn't work.  Check out [how to ask](http://superuser.com/help/how-to-ask) for some more info.

Comment: Thanks Bruce. Before posting the question, I have tried to remove duplicates, but that does not help with the start and stop date criteria. I did look at other options of removing duplicates in excel on the forum, but they would work if I had one column with dates than two. I think its do able, but do not have the experience to implement it :).

Answer (score 0):

I would use Power Query for this. Power Query is a free Add-In from Microsoft for Excel 2010 and 2013, and is built into Excel 2016 on the Data ribbon, under Get & Transform.

Power Query can read from Excel tables or named ranges. It has a Group By function that can calculate Min and Max values for your Start and Stop Date requirements.

For your conditional grouping requirement, I would add a Column to the Power Query design to group on e.g.

`if [Loc 3] = "Y" or [Loc 4] = "Y" then "Y" else "N"`

Then I would Group By that column, and calculate the Max of Loc 3 and Loc 4.